# Error: 1148 - The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version SQL=LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04

We moved our development code to `Ubuntu 14` server in `AWS`. When I tried to import local file data into the `mysql` database from my php application I got:

> "Error: 1148 - The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
>   SQL=LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE."

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.43

When I try the same load statement from `phpmyadmin` it works fine.

When I try the same load statement with the same database and from my staging server(front end)linux server in aws,it works fine but not with ubuntu.